# Is is it possible to Access sharePoint Site in my other application?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, jquery

I want to access the SharePoint List in my asp.net application I want to fetch the list using Jquery or Javascript code.How can I connect to sharepoint site in my javascript code? Please send me steps how can I do this.

Comment: Is your ASP.Net application within the same domain?